# How to remove rear hub covers

Tags: road-bike, wheels, repair, tools, bearings

I'm trying to service my DT Swiss wheels.

I watched some videos that show how to grease cartridge bearings but don't understand how to get to them. I tried to unscrew the ends using two adjustable wrenches but just ended up stripping the edge of the nuts.

How do I get he end nuts off the axle?

[image: how to get end off?]

[image: want to remove nuts and dust caps]

Comment: DT Swiss website has a lot of technical docs and manuals. Have you looked there? What model hub is it you have?

Comment: Adjustable wrenches will do that. They have a place in every tool box but are rarely the best tool for the job, and no substitute for the correct sized fixed spanner. An aircraft engineer once told me "If you have a problem, and use an adjustable spanner, you now have two problems :)

Comment: My Dad always called them 'nut lathes' for their ability to round off nuts.

Comment: Use the proper size wrenches.

Comment: Note that some hubs of this style have the inside of the axle cut to accept an allen wrench.  (Peek inside!)  If this is the case it's likely easier to hold things steady with an allen wrench than to use another (fixed-size) wrench on the opposite nut.  Among other things this spares you from having to have two sets of wrenches.

Comment: This seems like one of the more basic ones I've seen; 

There's two possibilities.

The axle where your quick-release skewer would go (if this hub and axle accepts them) may have an allen/hex wrench slot inset within. Put the correct size (most likely 4-5mm) and try and loosen off the cone. Or...

Put the correct size wrench on one side of the hub and one on the other and loosen.

 This hub seems to have no lockrings, so they're basically just cones that tighten to either a threshold or against each other. Give it a bash, (Not literally!) and let us know how it goes!

Answer (score 1):

For the inner nut you need a special wrench that is slimmer than a usual one - as slim as the nut is. For the outer nut a normal wrench will do - hold the inner one and turn the outer one until they no longer lock each other. Then you can take them off both.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Good answer, but I can't see any flats on the part labelled inner.  I fear we've missed something, but I don't know what.

Comment: I don't know this particular hub personally and assumed that it would work like other hubs that I know. In any case, the right tool will avoid any damage of the nuts. In this case now suspect that one has to use two wrenches to unscrew the two outer nuts on either side.

Comment: I usually unwind the bolts on each side of the hub against each other using two of the tools the poster has included in this answer.  I don't think there is an inner bolt for this hub as per the answer.  It's just a slide on spacer.

Comment: If it's a sealed bearing hub, they usually only have a pair of nuts. One left and one right. There's no cone to lock so no lock nuts for that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your hub doesn't have lock nuts, so you don't have to worry about inner/outer lock nuts.

You will need to get some better wrenches ([cone wrenchs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cone_wrench) would be best because they are as narrow as the flats on your axle nuts) and then with a wrench on both 'ends' of the axle you'll be able to loosen them.